# All the buttons in Excel 2002 have gone gray in the gui, can they be restored?

Tags: microsoft-excel, gui

Can the gui be restored?

Version is Excel 2002 10.6871.6870 SP3 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

This is how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: It's been a while since I've used 2002, but there should be an option menu to modify your toolbars.  Try resetting your toolbars to the default settings.  It looks like the toolbar's text colour is set to grey.

Answer (score 1):

What OS?  What Excel Version?

It may be you can wipe out the files under appdata (Win Vista +) or ApplicationData (XP -).  If you want to try this, I'd suggest:

1. Close Excel if already open
2. Backup all the above files to another folder (copy folders into some "backup" folder however you choose to name it.) .. (CAUTION: If you use a Personal.xls file or Personal Macro Workbook, be sure to back it up for certain.  It'll be in the "XLStart" folder.)
3. Delete everthing in the AppData Excel folder.  In Windows 10 with Excel 2016, that's at c:\users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel .. (Note1: AppData is hidden, you'll need to enable viewing hidden files and folders in Windows File Explorer) .. (Note2: You may also want to poke around under AppData\Local and/or AppData\LocalLow, but 99% of files of consequence are under Roaming.)